# Is ";so," an acceptable grammar structure?

Tags: commas, semicolons, coordinating-conjunctions

For a while, I've been using "so" with a semicolon.

For example, I would say, "I like bugs; so, I went to the bug convention happily."

I've always thought of the semicolon as a replacement for the coordinating conjunction in the sentence: "I like bugs, and, so, I went to the bug convention happily."

I haven't seen many other people use this construction, and I was wondering if anyone had any insight as to if this is correct or not.

Comment: Too much punctuation. Way too much punctuation. "I like bugs, so I went to the convention". "I like bugs, and so I went to the convention". That is all. As to semicolons specifically, the rule for using them is very simple. If you wonder whether you should use a semicolon, then you shouldn't.

Comment: It's fine. There is nothing wrong with starting a sentence with *so*, so there is nothing wrong with starting an independent clause with *so*. Any objection will be entirely on stylistic grounds, which is a matter of opinion. (I completely disagree with the previous comment—but that's just my opinion.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I never once objected to starting an independent clause with *so*. Not here, not elsewhere; not on stylistic grounds, not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The Corpus of Historical American English returns over a thousand hits for this construction so it's defninitely acceptable; however, it usually appears in much longer and more complex sentences.

E.g.

> There had not been such a freshet for years before, and there had
> never been one since **; so ,** as the quiet seasons went by, " Lucindy's
> log " was left in peace, the columbines blooming all about it, the
> harebells hanging their heads of delicate blue among the rocks that
> held it in place, the birds building their nests in the knot-holes of
> its withered side. (The Fall of the House of Usher, Poe, Edgar Allan, 1809-1849)
>
> And as upon the invasion of their valleys, the frosty Swiss have
> retreated to their mountains **; so ,** hunted from the savannas and
> glades of the middle seas, the whale-bone whales can at last resort to
> their Polar citadels, and diving under the ultimate glassy barriers
> and walls there, come up among icy fields and floes; and in a charmed
> circle of everlasting December, bid defiance to all pursuit from man. (Moby Dick or the whale, Melville, Herman, 1819-1891)
>
> Garcia and London, who earn their livings by lecturing and giving
> demonstrations of the pitfalls that await unwary cardplayers and
> pedestrians, are exceedingly skillful at sleight of hand **; so ,** of
> course, is Tannen, who bounced into sight behind Garcia and, with a
> snap of his fingers, caused a paper bouquet to materialize under our
> nose. (Talk of the Town; Cooper, Henry; New Yorker: 1960-01-23: p.
> 23-27)

Comment: All three of these examples are different from what the OP has.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had assumed that I would get an email notification when someone responded, but I didn't, so I apologize for the late response ;). I usually use the construction in longer sentences like those but have been doing so in shorter sentences as well. From now on, I will use a simple comma for sentences like that I used in my example and a semicolon for longer ones like the examples you have provided. Thank you all once more!